# THINC-API - SPEC NOT ACTIVE

Tags: api, okuma

Could you please help me to solve problem with thic THINC-API?
I inspected my CNC with [SCOUT](https://www.myokuma.com/scout) and got following information:

> ApiSpec=False
>   ThincApiInstalled=True
>   ApiInstallType=Basic
>   ThincApiCheckResult=VersionRecognized
>   ThincApiVersion=1.12.1.0-SPEC_NOT_ACTIVE

What should i do to get access to data?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your machine does not have the proper specification.

> #### Custom API (`CAPI`)
>
> Lathe and Multi-Tasking Machines: **NC-B Spec No. 4, Bit 0**
>   Machining Center: **NC Spec No. 32, Bit 2**

You can confirm in your program if a machine has this spec code enabled by [using SCOUT](https://github.com/OkumaAmerica/Open-API-SDK/tree/master/Scout):

> ```c#
>   bool HasCustomAPI = false;  
>     if (Okuma.Scout.Platform.BaseMachineType == Okuma.Scout.Enums.MachineType.L)  
>     {  
>         if (Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NCB.MachineSpecCodeFileExists)  
>         {  
>             if (Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NCB.SpecFileIsValid)  
>             {  
>                 HasCustomAPI = Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NCB.Bit(
>                     Okuma.Scout.Enums.NCBSpecGroup.NCB1MG, 4, 0);  
>             }  
>         }  
>     }  
>     else if (Okuma.Scout.Platform.BaseMachineType == Okuma.Scout.Enums.MachineType.M)  
>     {  
>         if (Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NC.MachineSpecCodeFileExists)  
>         {  
>             if (Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NC.SpecFileIsValid)  
>             {  
>                 HasCustomAPI = Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NC.Bit(
>                     Okuma.Scout.Enums.NCSpecGroup.NC1MG, 32, 2);  
>             }  
>         }  
>     }  
>     if (HasCustomAPI)  
>     {  
>         // ...  
>     }
> ```

The Okuma Open API (*THINC API*) requires this spec code to function.
**It comes standard with machines sold in the USA.**
For other counties, this is an option you will need to order.
Please contact your Okuma Representative.