# Okuma THINC API Dependency File Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, dll, okuma

I have to convert a very very simple program from Vb to C#.
The Vb has those references
[image]

From seeing here if I am not mistaken those should be managed dlls. I achieve the same result if I follow the procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275985/is-this-dll-managed-or-unmanaged) with the dumpbin.exe program.

So everything should be fine.
But when I do that `CWorkpiece instance = new CWorkpiece();` I get the following error

[image]

which tells that the relevant dll is not in the right place.
However the file is right were it should be
[image]

That said I have thought that perhaps I had done a wrong investigation but adding the following lines didn't help

```
    [DllImport("C:\\Temp\\1\\Okuma.CLDATAPI.dll")]
    public static extern int CWorkpiece();
```

So in short the problem is all related with that dll which can't be found
Thank you in advance for any help
Patrick

Comment: How did you add the reference before you tried to use DllImport? In the C# project, is there a little yellow triangle with "!" next to the reference?

Comment: As far as I know the dllimport should be only for unmanaged dlls. So here should be not necessary. However I added them right click on the project references ---> add reference --> browse. And no, no yellow warning sign there (see pic 1). In fact in pic 3 the dll is present

Comment: Try to make a new project. Add the reference and only one line with `CWorkpiece instance = new CWorkpiece();` - do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes :-( same dll missing error

Comment: Where is it located? Have you tried copying it into a folder inside the project structure and create the reference from there?

Comment: Are those dlls available through nuget?

Comment: I have also tried changing the location and also copying them into the folder. No those dlls are not available through nuget

Comment: You may obtain them as a part of the [Okuma Open API SDK](https://github.com/OkumaAmerica/Open-API-SDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Refer to Section "*4.5.1.3.3.1 Missing library file*" of the THINC API Installation Manual.

> [image: Ex Message]
>
> All applications developed with .NET THINC-API libraries are required to include an exact version of THINC-API libraries with the custom installation. THINC-API libraries compiled with application should
>   be installed with your application folder.
>
> The above error message shows that THINC-API library named Okuma.CLDATAPI.dll cannot be found at the folder where the application runs from.
>
> Solution: Include THINC-API libraries compiled in your application with your custom setup and re-install
>   your application with new setup.

Yes the THINC API libraries are managed .NET libraries. The command (CMD) API is written in VB, and the data API in VC++.  Depending on the API version you have, these libraries either written in .NET 1.1 or 4.0. 
So you really shouldn't be attempting to Pinvoke them.

The real problem you are facing is attempting to run your program in an environment which does not have the THINC API installed. Yes, you have the libraries referenced by your application, but that is not enough.

The THINC API libraries have several dependencies including:

- Okuma.FlexNet.dll
- Okuma.ApiLog.dll / Okuma.Api.LogService.dll
- LDATAPI.dll / MDATAPI.dll / GDATAPI.dll
- LCMDAPI.exe / MCMDAPI.exe / GCMDAPI.exe
- PIODlib.dll
- Softswitch.exe

---

## Solution

1. Obtain a copy of the API Install disc; either from a disc that has shipped with an Okuma machine, or a new version through your Okuma dealer.
2. Install the development version of the THINC API in your development environment.

Note that you will not be able to `Init()` or call any other API functions unless your environment is one of the following:

- An actual Okuma Machine with [CAPI Option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48775597/2596334) and THINC API Installed
- An "NC-Master" Simulator such as this: [image: P300A NC-Master Simulator]
- Or a PC NC-Master which is an **all software** simulator.